# Displaying value in combo box in a text field upon button click

Tags: java, combobox, click, jbutton, textfield

The 
The following method is executed when a button(jButton1) is clicked! I want to display the selected item in the combox(jComboBox1) in a textfield (jTextField3) when jbutton1 is clicked!

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if (evt.getSource() == jComboBox1 )

     type = (String)jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();

     jTextField3.setText(type);

}
```

But though there are no compile errors when running the program nothing is displayed in jTextField3! How can I correct this issue?

Comment: as a side note, please use `{` `}` **all** the time. Though I am not saying this will solve the issue rather as a good practice and prevent future unexpected results.

Comment: I used still its not working

Comment: what did you call your button? in other words, what is the variable name you've given it?

Comment: The name of the button is jButton1

Comment: Without a valid [mcve] it will be hard to know what is causing your bug. About the best I can guess is that the bug is not to be found in the code you've posted. Since *you* don't know where the bug is, how do you know if you've posted the pertinent code? You will likely want to create and post your MCVE so that you or we can find it.

Comment: @KasunKumara then shouldn't your `if` statement be --> `if (evt.getSource() == jButton1 )`?

Comment: @Aominè: good eyes. Indeed it should. Even better -- avoid listeners that require such constructs.

Answer (score -2):

It will work with

```
type = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Comment: please tell me the difference between this and what OP has already tried?

Comment: what does youe question mean?